# types and pointers address

Tags: c, pointers, pointer-arithmetic

Suppose the first element of double `u[100]` has address `0x1000`, and `sizeof(double)` is `8`. What does

```
printf("%p %p\n", &u[3] - 1, &u[20] - 5)
```

output?

The homework answer is

```
echo '0x1010 0x1078'
```

How did they do the second part `&u[20] - 5`?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Questions get downvoted for variety of reasons. Don't get discouraged by downvotes. Questions and answers of experienced SO users get downvoted too. See [ask].

Comment: @RSahu: You should have added questions have to show at least some effort by the asker to resolve the problem herself. In fact, this is a valid reason for downvotes. Similar if the question contains a rant about justified DVs. And badly formatted questions also don't attract positive feedback.

Comment: @Michael Gaskill: If you edit, edit all.

Comment: `(20-5) * sizeof (double) == 0x78`

Answer (score 4):

First of all, realise that an array is a sequence of values in successive memory locations: so the memory for `u` would be laid out as follows:

```
0x1000: u[0]
0x1008: u[1]
0x1010: u[2]
0x1018: u[3]
0x1020: u[4]
0x1028: u[5]
```

So if you did a `printf("%p\n", &u[3]);` (which means "`printf` a pointer (`%p`) for the address (`&`) of `u[3]`"), you'd expect `0x1018`.

But your code says `&u[3]-1`, so you'd think it would print one less than 0x1018, or `0x1017`. But C works differently: `&u[3]` is a pointer-to-double, so "one less than that" is the *previous* double: `0x1010`.

You can apply a similar argument for `&u[20]-5`

Answer (score 1):

So the first one can be found like this

if &u[0] == 0x1000 then &u[1] == 0x1008, &u[2] == 0x1010 &u[3] == 0x1018

Remember that 0x indicates a hexadecimal number, so 0x1010 is 0x1000 + 16(base 10)

then you need to know that in c, if you have a double* and you subtract 1 from it, that will decrement the value by sizeof(double), not by 1. This is called 'pointer arithmetic'

So all together you have &u[3] - 1 == 0x1018 - 8 == 0x1010